# Bubble Chart - d3js & json (data with 2 columns)

Tags: json, d3.js

I use d3js (https://d3js.org/)

I want to make a Bubble Chart (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) but I see that the data is in json

I have this data (no json)

```
 78 FFASQ
 73 AABB
 42 ACD
 30 KKLPDS
 16 TRI
 10 AFVA
 10 VASDABBB
  8 EC
  6 VDRREWSTW
  4 WERETRT
```

First column size

Second column, the name

I tried to replace the data in index.html but not working.

How can I do it?

I got the idea to convert my data to json, but do not know.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make a csv file with two columns (size and name). 
You can easily use the csv file replacing your example code line:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root)
```

in something like this:

```
d3.csv("yourcsvfile.csv", function(error, data)
```

I think this example can you help http://jrue.github.io/coding/2014/exercises/basicbubblepackchart/

Comment: I tried it and it has worked.
Thank you!

Now the only thing left is to see how to convert text to CSV format, but that's another topic.

Comment: Do you search a tool for convert txt in csv? Maybe you can use Python

Comment: Yes, I've searched but found nothing that works correctly me. Maybe it's my little knowledge in Linux and programming.

Comment: Try to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is not just because the source data is not in json format, you can load data in csv, tsv, xml formats. If you look at the example bl.ocks closer, you'll see that the source data `flare.json` has following structure:

```
{
 "name": "graph",
 "children": [
  {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
  {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
  {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
  {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
  {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
 ]
}
```

Because this demo is using a 'Hierarchy' layout - `d3.layout.pack()`, which is suitable for datasets which have a hierarchy structure. But in your description, the data doesn't seem to be a hierarchy structure.

I suggest that you might consider a different chart type, such as scatterplot, or if you can update the data structure, there are other forms of hierarchy layouts available, such as `treemap`, `sunburst` etc.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot with the concepts :)